# What does putting something under "target dependencies" in Xcode do?

Tags: xcode

If have two targets, A and B…  And say you give target A, a linked binary to a library, something like CoreLocation...

And then if you add target A to target B's "target dependencies", does that mean target B will automatically have CoreLocation?

I have often been confused with what adding things to target dependencies does, when to do it, why, etc.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not affect what is linked to a target.  Adding A to B's dependencies means that if you tell Xcode to build B, it will first build A.  The idea is that, for example, if A builds a library that is used in an app built by B, you probably want to have the most up to date version of the library before you build the app.

Comment: So I have a project with two targets-- my main app, and my test unit target.  The test unit target only has the test files in the compile sources section, and does not include any of the libraries in the main app.  Yet, it builds completely fine, and the test files have access to all of the classes / objects in the main app.  I would think the test target would need to manually have each of the main app's class files in the compile sources section-- but that's not the case.